# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to find out the feature importance for Random Forest Classification Task. But it gives me following error :

> 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

Here is a portion of my code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline


# importing dataset

dataset=pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:,3:12].values
Y = dataset.iloc[:,13].values

#spliting dataset into test set and train set

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.20)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=20, random_state=0)  
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train) 

#feature importance

feature_importances = pd.DataFrame(rf.feature_importances_,index = X_train.columns,columns=['importance']).sort_values('importance',ascending=False)
```

I expect this should give the features importance score for each column of my dataset. (Note: the original data is in CSV formate)

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the problem is. You are trying to access X_train.columns, but X_train is a numpy array and not a pandas dataframe, and it has no attribute columns

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline


# importing dataset

dataset=pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:,3:12].values
Y = dataset.iloc[:,13].values

#spliting dataset into test set and train set

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.20)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=20, random_state=0)  
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train) 

#feature importance

feature_importances = pd.DataFrame(regressor.feature_importances_,index = dataset.columns,columns=['importance']).sort_values('importance',ascending=False)
```

Comment: it gives the following error : 
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (468, 1), indices imply (14, 1)

Comment: can you post the data?

Answer (score 0):

So `X_train` that comes out from `train_test_split` is actually a numpy array which will never have a columns. 
Secondly, you are asking for values when you make `X` from `dataset` which returns the numpy.ndarry and not a df.

You need to changes your line

`feature_importances = pd.DataFrame(rf.feature_importances_,index = X_train.columns,columns=['importance']).sort_values('importance',ascending=False)`

to

`columns_ = dataset.iloc[:1, 3:12].columns`

```
feature_importances = pd.DataFrame(rf.feature_importances_,index = columns_,columns=['importance']).sort_values('importance',ascending=False)
```

Comment: This is giving following error -
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

Comment: Even when you replaced `X_train` with `X` ?

Comment: Secondly, you will want to use `regressor` instead of `rf`

Comment: Dude, so sorry just update the answer, I missed that you took values `X = dataset.iloc[:,3:12].values`

Comment: what can i do now ?? any suggestion please

Answer (score 0):

The iloc and loc functions could be applied to Pandas dataframe only. You are applying them in to an array.
Solution:
Convert the array into dataframe then apply the iloc or loc